# Rails 4 - Restrict retrieved columns from associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails, and while writing Active Record queries, I notice that ***all*** columns of ***all*** associated tables are being retrieved. I would like to tell Active Record which fields from which tables ought to be retrieved. How would go about doing that?

My models and their associations are as follows:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :comments
  has_many :posts
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

I'm following the Rails [Edge Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields), and when I try to use `select("users.id, profiles.first_name, profiles.last_name, comments.comment")` to specify the field lists, I get a deprecation warning on the Rails console (and the SQL query that is run is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` of all tables involved, but it still includes ***all*** columns):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one of: users, posts) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet. For example: 

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")

Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)

If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the feature entirely by setting `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. (called from irb_binding at (irb):34)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buried deep inside the Rails [Edge Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) for Active Record Query Interface, I found the answer. The trick is to use scopes for the particular association type where you want to restrict the retrieved fields.

Quoted directly from the guide:

> #### 4.1.3 Scopes for belongs_to
>
> There may be times when you wish to customize the query used by belongs_to. Such customizations can be achieved via a scope block. For example:

```ruby
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, -> { where active: true },
                    dependent: :destroy
end
```

> You can use any of the standard querying methods inside the scope block.

So, adding a `select` method to the above scope, with the list of fields you want retrieved will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check if following work for you

```
Class User < ActivcRecord::Base
   default_scope select("column1, column2, column3")

end
```

Comment: I already looked into `default_scope`, but the problem is that it restricts the specified columns for **all** queries to the model. What if I want different sets of columns for different queries? Will the regular `scope` work?

Comment: You can do it in following way 

Post.select(:field1, :field2).find(id)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, that works for the Post model, and I don't get any deprecation warning. Now, how would I restrict fields on an associated model? Say, I want to do something like `User.select(:field1, :field2).includes(:posts)`, how would I restrict the fields retrieved from the `Post` model?

Comment: Your answer regarding `default_scope` got me looking around in the Edge Guides, and I found the answer buried deep inside the guide itself. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!